# Passing arguments to a function with both container and element type templates

Tags: c++, templates

This should be an easy fix, but I am baffled looking the web to find how to pass the arguments of a function that has container and element type templates. I have the following implementation of a binary search tree and calling it in the main function throws an error of unmatching arguments with the function template.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename ElementType>
struct BTreeNode
{
    ElementType value;
    BTreeNode<ElementType>* left;
    BTreeNode<ElementType>* right;
};

template <typename ElementType>
void Insert(BTreeNode<ElementType> ** root, int value)
{
    if (*root == NULL)
    {
        *root = new node(value);
    }
    else if ((*root)->value <= value)
    {
        insert(&((*root)->pRight), value);
    }
    else if ((*root)->value > value)
    {
        insert(&((*root)->pLeft), value);
    }
}


template <typename ContainerType, typename ElementType> 
BTreeNode<ElementType>* CreateBST(const ContainerType & elements, const size_t num_elements)
{
    BTreeNode<ElementType> * root = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
    {
        Insert(&root, elements[i]);
    }
    return root;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> x = { 10, 5, 15, 5, 6, 7, 8, 89 };
    BTreeNode<int> * tree = CreateBST(x, x.size());
    //inOrderTraversal(pRoot);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must pass the data types while creating the instances of the class/structs or calling the templated methods:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the 2nd template parameter `ElementType` of `CreateBST` is non-deducible, you need to specify it explicitly like

```
BTreeNode<int> * tree = CreateBST<std::vector<int>, int>(x, x.size());
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or you can remove the template parameter `ElementType`, make `CreateBST` get it from `ContainerType` (e.g. STL containers have the member type `value_type`).

```
template <typename ContainerType> 
BTreeNode<typename ContainerType::value_type>* CreateBST(const ContainerType & elements, const size_t num_elements)
{
    BTreeNode<typename ContainerType::value_type> * root = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
    {
        Insert(&root, elements[i]);
    }
    return root;
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
BTreeNode<int> * tree = CreateBST(x, x.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename ElementType>
struct BTreeNode
{
    ElementType value;
    BTreeNode<ElementType>* left;
    BTreeNode<ElementType>* right;
    BTreeNode(ElementType & t):value(t){}
};

template <typename ElementType>
void Insert(BTreeNode<ElementType> ** root, ElementType value)
{
    if (*root == NULL)
    {
        *root = new BTreeNode<ElementType>(value);
    }
    else if ((*root)->value <= value)
    {
        Insert(&((*root)->right), value);
    }
    else if ((*root)->value > value)
    {
        Insert(&((*root)->left), value);
    }
}


template <typename ContainerType, typename ElementType>
BTreeNode<ElementType>* CreateBST(const ContainerType & elements, const size_t 
num_elements)
{
     BTreeNode<ElementType> * root = NULL;
     for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
     {
         Insert<ElementType>(&root, elements[i]);
     }
     return root;
 }


 int main()
 {
    std::vector<int> x = { 10, 5, 15, 5, 6, 7, 8, 89 };
    BTreeNode<int> * tree = CreateBST<vector<int>, int>(x, x.size());
    //inOrderTraversal(pRoot);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

There were few other mistakes in your code including not initializing the dynamic/template argument types. For the compiler to derive the types of the templated parameters at the compile time, it is necessary to pass the template types(the actual data type of parameters you are going to use) while creating an object or making a method call. As C/C++ are typed languages, they need to resolve the types of the variable/parameters at compile time. For a template class, you don't have to explicitly make method calls using `method_name<typename>` format, just initializing the class instance with the type suffices for the compiler to derive the type for all the methods defined inside it. But for methods outside of a class, you need to specify the type every time you make the method call.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can't work out what type `ElementType` is in your call to `CreateBST()` because none of the arguments to the function constrain it.

You've got a couple of options:

### Explicitly specify the types

```
auto* tree = CreateBST<decltype(x), int>(x, x.size());
```

Short and sweet but maybe a bit awkward.

### Derive ElementType from ContainerType

Most of the standard library containers expose a `value_type` typedef that is the type they store:

```
template <typename ContainerType, typename ElementType = typename ContainerType::value_type> 
BTreeNode<ElementType>* CreateBST(const ContainerType & elements, const size_t num_elements)
{
    BTreeNode<ElementType> * root = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
    {
        Insert(&root, elements[i]);
    }
    return root;
}
```

This will work, and is fairly straightforward, but it won't work for everything you might want to pass as a ContainerType - your function supports anything with an `operator[]`, and this only works for things that expose a `value_type` typedef.

### Derive ElementType from the return value of ContainerType::operator[]

```
template <typename ContainerType, typename ElementType = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::declval<ContainerType>()[0])>> 
BTreeNode<ElementType>* CreateBST(const ContainerType & elements, const size_t num_elements)
{
    BTreeNode<ElementType> * root = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
    {
        Insert(&root, elements[i]);
    }
    return root;
}
```

This has a few moving parts:

- We want to get the return type of `ContainerType::operator[]`, so we instantiate an instance of ContainerType via `std::declval<ContainerType>()`, and then call `operator[]`.
- We get the type of that expression using `decltype()`
- Most operator[] functions return a reference, and we don't want that, so we pass the result to `std::remove_reference`